# doing math with margins and width in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, margins

What I am trying to do is have content always be in the center of a container even if the margin size and content size change. This also means that the container size must change on it's own given the amount of margin and width of the content. Here is a js fiddle that has a general set-up of a function and an alert that gives the output: **http://jsfiddle.net/jpY5n/**

```
function resizeContainer(size, distance) {
var postWidth = size;
var postApart = distance * 3;
return postWidth + postApart;
};
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#container').width(resizeContainer($("#content").width(),$("#content").css("margin-left"));
});
```

I could theoretically use the function I have set up in order to change the width of the posts, but it can't take in the math of the margins because, as you can see in the alert, the margin is **10px**, not 10, so the math comes back as **NaN**...Is there a way to to make the margin settings let us say ßpx to just ß?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the numeric value of the margin by parsing the string into a `Number` after replacing `'px'` with `''`:

```
var margin = Number($('#content').css('margin-left').replace('px',''));
```

[Here's the updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpY5n/1/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript (jQuery)**

```
function resizeContainer(size, distance) {
    var postWidth = size * 2;
    var postApart = distance * 3;
    return postWidth + postApart;
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("Container width should be set to " + $("#content").width() + " times 2 plus " + $("#content").css("margin-left") + " times 3");
    var width = Number($('#content').width());
    var margin = Number($('#content').css('margin-left').replace('px',''));
    $('#content').width(resizeContainer(width,margin));
});
```